# Alguien sabe cual es el error en el codigo ? (se queda estancado)

Tags: java, array

es un código en donde la idea es que luego de insertar el nombre de ciertos procesos, estos se detengan, funciona pidiendo los nombres de los procesos a detener, los cuales se guardan en un array, este debe ser leído por un método que se encarga de cerrar los procesos, el problema es que a la hora ejecutarse ese método, el programa queda estancado. Ya he probado el método poniendo el nombre de un proceso manualmente y funciona, pero a la hora de decirle que lea los datos del array, el programa se atasca.

```
package foroverflow;
public class ForOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de procesos a detener: ");
        ForOverflow1 obj = new ForOverflow1();
        obj.Procesos_aaa();
        ForOverflow2.killProcess();
    }
}

package foroverflow;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ForOverflow1 {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Procesos[] = new String [in.nextInt()];  
    public void Procesos_aaa() {
        in.nextLine();
        for(int con = 0; con < Procesos.length; con++) {
            System.out.print("Ingresa el nombre del " + ++con + " proceso, (x ej: chrome.exe): ");
            Procesos[--con] = in.nextLine();
         }
    }
    public String[] getProcesos() {
        return Procesos;
    }
}

package foroverflow;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class ForOverflow2 {
    private static final String TASKLIST = "tasklist";
    private static final String KILL = "taskkill /F /IM ";

    public static boolean isProcessRunning(String serviceName) throws Exception {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(TASKLIST);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
                if (line.contains(serviceName)) {
                    return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void killProcess() throws Exception {
        ForOverflow1 obj = new ForOverflow1();
        for (String aaa : obj.getProcesos()) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(KILL + aaa);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver, al método `killProcess` le deberías de pasar la lista de objetos que has ingresado en `Procesos_aaa`. Lo que estás haciendo es crear un objeto **nuevo** de tipo `ForOverflow1` en el método `killProcess`. Este nuevo objeto **no** tiene la lista que se crea en `Procesos_aaa`, es una lista vacia. Deberias cambiar el diseño de tu aplicación. A grosso modo algo así:

```
public class ForOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de procesos a detener: ");
        ForOverflow1 obj = new ForOverflow1();
        obj.Procesos_aaa();
        ForOverflow2.killProcess(obj.getProcesos());
    }
}

// clase ForOverflow1 ...

public class ForOverflow2 {
    // lo mismo que tienes ...

    public static void killProcess(String Procesos[]) throws Exception {
        for (String aaa : Procesos) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(KILL + aaa);
        }
    }
}
```